# makefile performs target even without any changes

Tags: makefile

I have a simple `makefile` that works fine, but it seems to perform
the `all` target even if no changes occurred. I would expect a

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Message, but it keeps executing the target whenever I call `make`.
Here is my simple makefile:

```
BASEDIR = /home/someuser/STA
SRC_DIR = ${BASEDIR}/src
OBJ_DIR = ${BASEDIR}/obj
INC_DIR = ${BASEDIR}/inc

SRC_FILES        = $(wildcard  ${SRC_DIR}/*.cpp)
SRC_FILES_NOTDIR = $(notdir    ${SRC_FILES})
OBJ_FILES_NOTDIR = $(patsubst  %.cpp, %.cpp.o, ${SRC_FILES_NOTDIR})
OBJ_FILES        = $(addprefix ${OBJ_DIR}/,${OBJ_FILES_NOTDIR})
INC_FILES        = $(wildcard  ${INC_DIR}/*.h)

all: ${OBJ_FILES}
    g++ ${OBJ_FILES} -o program

${OBJ_DIR}/%.cpp.o: ${SRC_DIR}/%.cpp ${INC_FILES}
    g++ -I${INC_DIR} -o $@ -c $<
```

And here is what printed to terminal when I call `make` twice:

```
$ make
g++ <somedir/file1>.cpp.o <somedir/file2>.cpp.o -o program
$ make
g++ <somedir/file1>.cpp.o <somedir/file2>.cpp.o -o program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `all` that is not a file and does not exist (reason why make tries to build it each time) by `program`, a real file that make can see. If you really want an `all` symbolic target, declare it as [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) and add a rule without recipe to tell make that `all` depends on `program`:

```
.PHONY: all
all: program
```